# In Org Mode, how to get path of an attachment - given its ID - in a string format?

Tags: org-mode

In Org Mode I have an [attachment](http://orgmode.org/manual/Attachments.html) associated with some task

```
* Some task                                                          :ATTACH:
  :PROPERTIES:
  :Attachments: some_file.png
  :ID:       da335ac9-00ac-494b-9073-d17e70457bc8
  :END:
```

How to obtain a full path, in a string format, to `some_file.png` based on its ID?